# How to select predictors before having a response variable collected

Tags: predictive-models, feature-selection

I have a number of predictor variables collected. They are a few too many for practical use, and I'd like to trim my variable set. To do that, I thought I'd look for the variables that don't bring in unique variance in the dataset, i.e., the ones that are a combination of others.

Is it a legitimate strategy to reduce the number of variables? How would I do it practically? If I go ahead with the rather trivial idea of modelling each variable as a linear combination of others, what would be a good cut-off R^2 to flag a variable as redundant?

Alternatively, could I estimate the amount of uniqueness in a dataset and look at the drop in it if a predictor variable is excluded?

Comment: Check out principal components analysis.